# Alternative function for group inorder to improve the performance in a xfrom

Tags: xpath, xforms, orbeon

Can we use an alternate function other than group to perform the same action. The scenario I am trying to workout using group is - I have multiple pages in a form and a summary button on the first page which on being clicked should show the summary of all pages.

The logic we tried  was using group to club each individual pages by having a form variable which turns true when the summary button is clicked and we check this variables value in all pages and so when the summary button is clicked this condition satisfies and all the pages are displayed.

The Code Snippet

```
<Xforms:group id="page-1" 
              ref=".[instance('form')/current-page = '1' 
                      or 
                     instance('form')/summary = 'true']">
```

Using group fn drastically depreciates the performance. Is there any method to perform the same scenario. Kindly advise.

Comment: when `summary` is true, you want to show all the "pages" and otherwise you only show the current "page"; is that correct? What is the performance issue you are seeing: does it take a long time for Orbeon Forms to produce the page, or for the browser to render it? How many controls do you have one the form when all the controls are shown (`summary = 'true'`)?

Comment: @Avernet, Yes you are right that's what is needed. Previously we where using switch case to navigate to these pages. At that time the navigation time was really quick. In order to implement this summary view concept we have introduced group fn instead switch case. Now the time taken for navigation through the pages is really very slow when compared to the previous method. Controls shown when (summary = 'true') is nearly 500

Comment: thank you for the clarifications. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, hidden groups and hidden cases work differently:

- The controls in hidden groups are non-relevant.
- The controls in hidden cases are relevant.

As a result, using a switch/case, the server has to do more work to maintain and update the state of controls in hidden cases, but switching to a another case is very fast: it is pretty much just a matter of changing a class in the HTML, as the values of all the controls are already there. With hidden groups, when "switching to another group", the values for the controls in that group are sent by the server to the browser. Updating the values can take a little bit of time, especially if you have a lot of controls, say in a repeat.

It is hard to give a recommendation without really running your code, but if the time taken to do a switch is mostly spent on the browser, you could investigate using the [full update](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-performance-settings#TOC-Full-update-mechanism) mechanism. If the time is mostly spent on the server, then I'd look into [XPath analysis](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-xpath-analysis). (Note that both features are PE-only.)